# Is it possible using Media Source Extensions to extract only audio stream?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, internet-explorer-11, media-source

I want to try to implement transferring audio stream from client to server via http using html5 instead of flash. Now I am collecting information. I want my solution to work on opera,firefox, safari, chrome, and this ... ie. The problem is with this .. ie.

As far as I understand I need Web Audio Api. According to https://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie-11.html IE11 doesn't support Web Audio Api. However, according to the same link Media Source Extensions (MSE) is also not supported. However, here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn594470(v=vs.85).aspx I read:

> Internet Explorer 11 introduces support for MPEG-DASH media streaming
>   through HTML5 Media Source Extensions (MSE). MSE extends the video and
>   **audio** elements that you can dynamically change for a media stream
>   without using plug-ins. This gives you such things as adaptive media
>   streaming, live streaming, splicing videos, and video editing.
>
> Important  This feature is not supported in IE11 on Windows 7.

So, is it possible using Media Source Extensions to extract only audio stream for sending it to server to make cross-browser solution using javascript and html5?

Comment: per my understanding MediaSource is for the other way (from chunks from server to mediaElement)